# country culture flag database export?

Tags: php, mysql, database, geolocation, country-codes

Does anyone know a database that I can export, I need world countries information including: country code, culture (ex. en_US), flag image and currency.

I'm tried to google it, but haven't found anything.

Comment: I think you mean "import", not export.

Comment: yes, export from somewhere, and import in my db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't help with anything else, but for the flags, I'd have a look at the FamFamFam set found [here](http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/flags/). These flags fit in perfectly with the country codes that [GeoIP](http://www.jameslittle.me.uk/detect-visitors-country-with-php-mysql/) has, however these are two character codes (GB, US, FR, etc), not exactly what you were looking for.

As for currencies, I'm rather stumped. There might be a table out there somewhere, but if not, you could create an approximation; just have $, £ and Euro, with a default of $ perhaps?

Comment: Thx. Found the flags. Approximation isn't enough, I'm building a global system, need the currency and culture locale of every country

Comment: I haven't found any db which has all the data, so I combined a few. Links from you answer where really useful. Most of the data I got from GeoLite, icons from FamFamFam and culture locales I had to update on my own manually. Anyway job done. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for Geonames! It took me a while to find it, myself. I'm not sure why that is, because it's a fantastic resource.

Among many, many other data, Geonames provides the data you seek for countries of the world:

http://www.geonames.org/countries

---

### Example of the data provided:

#### [Brunei](http://www.geonames.org/countries/BN/brunei.html)

**country name**:   Brunei    [[other languages](http://www.geonames.org/BN/other-names-for-brunei.html)]

**iso code**:   BN, 096 and BRN

**fips code**:  BX

**capital**:    Bandar Seri Begawan

**area**:   5,770.0 km²

**population**:     395,027

**currency**:   Dollar (BND)

**languages**:  Malay (macrolanguage) (ms-BN), English (en-BN)

**neighbours**:     Malaysia

**postal code format**:     @@####

[image: http://www.geonames.org/flags/x/bn.gif]

Answer (score 1):

The following links provides free download of all the countries in various styles and sizes.
The flags are named with full name of the country.

http://www.free-country-flags.com/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link that my have exactly what you are looking for. The only catch, it's not free. But for AUD 10 it is a good deal considering the time it would take to compile this sort of database.

You will find a database in mysql format, csv, excel, and Access containing tables with country names, image names of corresponding flags, alpha 2 and alpha 3 country codes, over 4000 states linked to the countries via alpha 2 code table, currency names and currency codes belonging to the countries and there is also a directory with country flag images included in the downloadable .zip file.

To put all this together would take days of work, so it is money well spent if you really need this sort of database.
Here is the link to the download.

http://www.lasser.com.au/downloads/country-and-region-list

Comment: Thanks, nice. I already put together my own database from various sources. Didn't take that much time, certainly not days

Answer (score 1):

Here I collected countries with their flags, cities with their photos and other various information inside MySQL database:

https://github.com/turalus/openDB

Answer (score 0):

Inversely to @JamWaffles, I can't supply icons, but I can provide you with a decent list of country/currency codes.

I found the info on [PayPal XDevelopers site](https://www.x.com/community/home) about a year ago, but I can't find the exact page.

Sample:

```
'USD' => array(
'title' => 'U.S. Dollar',
    'symbol_left' => '&#36;', // $
    'symbol_right' => '',
    'decimal_point' => '.',
    'thousands_point' => ',',
    'decimal_places' => 2)
```

See the full array at https://gist.github.com/1161248

You can also grab a database of currency data, but I haven't looked at it, never mind used it before. http://www.unece.org/etrades/download/archives.htm

Comment: Thanks. I just found that PHP server should have that already with the localeconv() function. Now I just need a db of 2digit country codes, along with the locales format (ex. en_US)